# PCA dimension reduction, scikit-learn

Tags: variables, plot, scikit-learn, controls, pca

I have a dataset, the size is (21263, 81). I need to reduce the first 81 columns to 2 dimensions and plot it.
However, the last column is a continual variable (temperature), not a categorical variable as I normally see. When plotting the 2D figure, if I need to use the last column to control the point size, how do I write the python code?
Thank you.

Comment: A representative sample of your data may help

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Sergey, I've resolved it.